# Open a PDF and add pages to it in an Android app?

Tags: android, pdf

I generate a PDF document from user input. This document is then displayed and "signed" by the user.

I need to grab this signature and append it to the document. I'm generating the PDF using Android API and displaying using an external library, but I need a way to re-open the document after signing and modifying it.

It's mandatory to generate the PDF before signing it, so the user can review it.

Answer (score 0):

if the pdf file is saved to your storage after creating and updating it then try to read the file again otherwise you need to store the document first